# How to get quote_id in "checkout_cart_product_add_after" event

Tags: magento-1.9, quote

I have added `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event in my custom module like :

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <custom_detect_product_changes>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>custom/observer</class>
            <method>customFunction</method>
        </custom_detect_product_changes>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

And in `Observer.php` I want to get quote_id like :

```
...
public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // here I want to get quote_id

}
...
```

How to get `quote_id` in `customFunction`?

Comment: have you got solution of it??

Comment: I don't know your purpose of the customFunction but if you observer the checkout_cart_product_add_after you will miss actions like updating the cart or removing a product.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
      $quoteId = $observer->getQuoteItem()->getQuote()->getId();
}
```

You can get quote Id like this.

Comment: It is not working when first item added into quote, it is only working when quote already initiated and have at least one item in cart.

Comment: What do you want to do in this function ?
If you are use "checkout_cart_add_product_complete" observer instead of "checkout_cart_product_add_after"

Comment: I am using both event in my custom module, in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event, I want to set custom price to cart item.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Quote id using this code:

```
<?php $quote = $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote(); 
    var_dump($quote->getQuoteId());

?>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the quote id from checkout session like below:

```
$session        = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote_id       = $session->getQuoteId();
```

I hope this will help you.