# How to set custom price for quote item in checkout_cart_add_product_complete event

Tags: magento-1.9, quoteitem

I have two event observer in my custom module :

```
// 1st : checkout_cart_product_add_after
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $item->setIsNew(true);

// 2nd : checkout_cart_add_product_complete
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $quote_id = $quote->getId(); // quote_id
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $quote_item)
    {
        if($quote_item->getIsNew() == true)
        {
            $item = $quote_item;
        }
    }
    // here I want to set custom quote item price and tried below code but it is not working
    $item->setCustomPrice($current_tour_price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($current_tour_price);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $item->save(); // updated
```

I want to set custom price to quote item in `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event.

If I am using the code `setCustomPrice` and `setOriginalCustomPrice` in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event then it is working.

But I need `quote_id` as well with dynamic price for some other use and I can't get `quote_id` in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event, so I am using `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event.

How to set quote item custom price in event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`?

**EDIT :**
With `$item->save()` it save custom price for quote_item but on change currency custom price not going to update.

I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/38243913/4073217 but it is not working in my case.

How to set custom price for quote_item which work with currency change?

Answer (score 1):

You can always update quote, hack it, change value directly in database, but it would be overkill and so far from best practice.

If you need quote_id, you can easily grab it from `checkout_card_product_add_after` event, because it set quote_item during event dispatch:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
```

All you have to do in your observer is:

```
$quote_id = $this->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getQuote()->getId();
```

Comment: Please check my question I'm able to get quote_id in event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` and want to set custom price for quote_item. and not able to get quote_id in event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`.

Comment: There is no reason why you cannot achieve the same thing in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` as you're doing in `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`. Just use `$this->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getQuote()` and do whatever you need with quote items.

Comment: please check this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156952/14039.

Comment: I still think that your business logic can be defined on the other way. But, let's not go further with it, you can try to rewrite Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart, and in addProduct() function, just add new event dispatch before `return $this;`.  Something like: `Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after_custom', array('quote' => $this->getQuote(), 'quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));`. If there is no quote_id set, just add check and call save(), and live with that little overhead.

Comment: Please check my edit question.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2:

You can achieve this with Event and Observer. There are following steps:

- Step 1: Create Simple Extension
- Step 2: Declaration of Module
- Step 3: Registration of Module
- Step 4: Activate the Module
- Step 5: Declare event
- Step 6: Create Observer for Custom Price

We need to catch the event - checkout_cart_product_add_after in step 5. In the Observer, write the code to set the custom price.